# retornar True si al menos un elemento de una lista es 2 o 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

En una lista de 2 enteros deseo que retorne True si contiene un 2 o un 3 con el siguiente código:

```
 def has23(nums):
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 2 or nums[i] == 3:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Por ejemplo si pruebo con esto:

```
print(has23([5, 3]))
```

Retorna:

```
False
```

Comment: ¿cual es el problema? , ¿cual es la entrada `nums`? ¿cual es la salida que obtienes?

Comment: ejemplo print(has23([5, 3])) retorna False pero si tengo un 3 en la lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera iteración para la lista de tu ejemplo (`[5, 3]`) obtiene el 5 de la lista, lo cual desencadena en:

```
if 5 == 2 or 5 == 3:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

El `if` obviamente no se cumple, por lo que entra en el `else` y la función retorna `False` y termina sin ni siquiera comprobar el resto de items de la lista. Ten en cuenta que cualquier sentencia return que se ejecute en cualquier parte de una función ocasiona que la ejecución de la misma termine en ese mismo punto, sin importar el código que quede por ejecutar.

La solución es tan simple como eliminar el `else`, retornar `True` solo si el `if` se cumple, en caso contrario pasar al siguiente elemento sin más y solo retornar `False` cuando la iteración sobre la lista termine (si ningún `if` se cumplió es porque ningún elemento es un 2 o un 3):

```
def has23(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 2 or nums[i] == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Por otro lado, no uses indexado y `range` para iterar sobre la lista, es más eficiente y "pitónico" usar un `for in`:

```
def has23(nums):
    for n in nums:
        if n == 2 or n == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Analicemos tu solución con la entrada: `[5, 3]`

*Cuando `i = 0` entonces `num[i]` es `5`, asi que el `if nums[i] == 2 or nums[i] == 3:` es falso por lo que se ejecutara el else, y en el else se retorna False, y recuerda que cuando se llama return se termina de ejecutar la funcion, eso evita que se analice cuando `i = 1`. Por lo anterior obtienes esa respuesta.*

Por otro lado no uses:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
```

sino puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
for num in nums:
```

que es más legible.

Una posible solución usando la logica de iterar puede ser la siguiente:

```
def has23(nums):
    for num in nums:
        if num == 2 or num ==3:
            return True
    return False
```

Es decir si al menos `num` es `2` o es `3` se retorna en caso contrario se sigue iterando, y si no se retorna nada en el loop se retorna False al final.

Pero python tiene otras instrucciones como `any` y `all`, el primero retorna `True` si en lista al menos hay un True y en otros casos False, y el segundo solo retorna True si todos son True. Y tambien la instruccion `in` que usado en un if retorna `True` si un elemento esta en un iterable. Usando lo anterior obtenemos:

```
def has23(nums):
    return any(val in nums for val in (2, 3))
```

Comment: Estoy planteando en Meta que todas las preguntas de Python muestren una sugerencia para que los usuarios etiqueten de forma más preciso. ¿Podrías darle un vistazo? [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83). Tu opinión sería interesante pues eres de los más reputados en esta etiqueta. ¡Gracias!